# Hide text in modern page using CSS - SPO

Tags: sharepoint-online, css, modern-pages, hide-elements

I have a modern SPO page and i want to hide the text "Add Link" using CSS. I found the class and used the below style in Modern Script editor webpart to hide the text but it is not working:

Can someone tell me what i am doing wrong?

[image]

```
<style type="text/css">
.ms-HorizontalNavItem {
display: none !important;
}
</style>
```

HTML Element Details:

[image]

Comment: Can you please post a screen capture about the html element details in Developer Tool (F12) ?

Comment: @Jerry_MSFT Screenshot of HTML element details added

Answer (score 0):

You can try to modify as below:

```
<style type="text/css">
  button.ms-HorizontalNavItem-link {
  display: none !important;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: Even this did not work.

Comment: Try to trace the css style using Developer Tool to see if it applied. If the same issue not working, try to use id selector : button#HorizontalNav1EditLink